# How do I change my python version to 3.5.2 in CentOS Linux?

Tags: linux, centos

My Linux box has python version 2.6.6 and I want to change/update the python version to 3.5.2 or later releases. The box has no internet connection, no pip working, no apt* working. Looking for help as I'm a noob in this area. All I have is a Python version 3.5.2 downloaded from internet and moved it to /usr/bin
Also Updated the ~/.bashrc file, but no changes happened, result is shown in screenshot.
Used this update command too but not worked `alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5.2 2`

[image]

[image]

[image]

TIA!!

Comment: looks like you're tryng to run a windows application on a linux machine. that is not going to work.

Comment: @Alex, pardon my ignorance, can you help me provide the link to download the linux compatible version?

Comment: My linux version is CentOS 6.5, FYI

Answer (score 0):

`whereis python` will show you the current situation, which is probably a symlink to the previous python version.
Just replace that symlink, so it points to `/usr/bin/python3.5.2`

Comment: `whereis python` gives me the output `python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz` . Also the directory structures of the paths `/usr/bin` and `/etc/alternatives` screenshots are attached in my main post FYR.

Comment: is `/usr/bin/python`  a symlink to `/usr/bin/python2.6` ?

Comment: when i give the cmd `cd /usr/bin/python`, it's taking me into that path and showing the contents also inside it but can't see the folder there anyways when checked. I stand corrected, when I goto `/usr/bin/python` using winscp tool, it's showing me the path `/usr/bin/python3.5.2`

Comment: but I asked if it was a symlink. For me, `/usr/bin/python` points to `/etc/alternatives/python` , which points to `/usr/bin/python3.7`

Comment: For me, `/usr/bin/python` points to `/etc/alternatives/python3.52` which inturn points to `/usr/bin/python3.5.2`